# Measure the efficiency of appending integers to a large dictionary of lists

Tags: python, performance, memory

I use the following python code to measure the efficiency of appending elements to a large dictionary of lists. The dictionary has `N` entries. Each entry is a list of `M` integers. So I assume that memory taken is about `N * M * 4bytes`. If `N` is 1 million and `M` is 300, then `1M * 300 * 4bytes`, namely, 1.2 Gigabytes should be taken. But to my surprise, python's `sys.getsizeof` only reported 40 Megabytes memory consumption. Where did I do wrong?

```
import sys
import time

N=1000000
M=300

start = time.time()

d={}
for n in range(N):
    d[n]=[]
    for m in range(M):
        d[n].append(m)


print ("Time elapsed in seconds = {}".format(time.time() - start))
print ("Size in Megabytes = {} ".format(sys.getsizeof(d)/1024.0/1024.0))
```

The code above reported

```
Time elapsed in seconds = 54.5907461643219
Size in Megabytes = 40.00010681152344
```

So, why is 40 Megabytes, instead of 1.2 Gigabytes memory usage reported?

Comment: How did you arrive at ```1.2 Gigabytes```? Seems wrong

Comment: 1M*300*4byte=1.2 Gigabytes. Anything wrong in there?

Comment: Also, your assumption that each int takes four bytes memory space is wrong. It's much more, as a Python object will be created for each. `sys.getsizeof(1)` returns 28 on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation, it says:

> Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.
> [...]
> See recursive sizeof recipe for an example of using getsizeof() recursively to find the size of containers and all their contents.

So, you're getting the size of your container (the dictionary), not the size of everything that's inside. There's also a link to get the "recursive" size at https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/

One way to verify this is that if you remove the "append" part to the array, you'll still get 40 MB size.